# VBA Run time error 91. Trouble setting object variable

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I don't think the answer is too complicated, I must just be missing something basic. To give context, the code and this macro were written by an employee who was no longer working here when I started. I have just used it a number of times on a monthly basis and it suddenly gave me an error today when I attempted to run the VBA script.

It gives me the standard `Run Time Error 91 (Object variable or block variable not set)`. The code specifically is:

```
Dim DataBook As Workbook
Set DataBook = Workbooks.Open(Import_File_Path)
DataBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Database"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Tool.Worksheets("Database").Delete      <-----highlighted error line
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

DataBook.Worksheets("Database").Move before:=Tool.Worksheets(1)
```

The VBA script is attempting to take raw data from an Excel sheet that I have already generated, and import the file (thus that part in the `Set` line) and perform a number of calculations to create more data and stats from there. However the problem I feel lies in the section I posted here and the objects and variables.

The highlighted error row is the one that says `Tool.Worksheets("Database").Delete`. When I added a Watch to that row the value states `Object Variable or With block variable not set`. This leads me to believe something is not being set as it should as an object, but again I am a VBA newbie and I am not confident about any of my gut feelings.

For what its worth, I should mention I added another `Watch` to the line that says `DataBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Database"`  and the value for that states `Subscript out of range`. I thought that meant it could also be a problem, however I am 100% sure there is a tab in the file I am importing that is named `Sheet1`.

Comment: What is Tool ... what kind of object it is?

Comment: Tool is currently defined "As ThisWorkbook".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some lines of code that establish **Tool** as a workbook.   Something like:

```
Dim Tool As Workbook
Set Tool = ActiveWorkbook
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Where in my coding would I place those lines? Before the "Application.DisplayAlerts" line? Again im a new VBA guy so Im not entirely sure about what Im doing. Thanks again

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I tried other websites and youre answer, simple as it may be was the best of all. Just to let you know you made my day by fixing this! Thanks a ton

Comment: This is called a declaration and normally lives at the top of the function, class or application depending on its scope

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Dim DataBook As Workbook
Set DataBook = Workbooks.Open(Import_File_Path)

DataBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Database"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
DataBook.Worksheets("Database").Delete      <-----Change
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

DataBook.Worksheets("Database").Move before:=Tool.Worksheets(1)
```